# Is there a way to get unique int key for elements in HashMap<String,String> ?

Tags: java, hashmap

Wondering is there a way to get unique integer key for each elements in HashMap. I have considered hashCode() but realized unique key is not guaranteed.   Can write a separate program using various algorithm but looking for some light weight built in solution within Java. HashMap will have max 100 elements.

Comment: Search for 'perfect hash functions'. In general, it cannot be known without knowing the inputs. It also doesn't really apply in general for a HashMap which has a varying capacity and applies a secondary hash function. It is a good thing HashMap also uses `equals` - the hash code is only for initial bucket selection.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. *Why* are you wanting an integer key?

Comment: @chrylis  It has to embedded in the  code which is already using SparseArray (SparseBooleanArray ) , unfortunately  SparseArray require Integer as key. to give you more details entries will be like hashMap("paris", "------------") and in sparseArray status will be updated using int key

Comment: If the map is naturally `<String, String>`, don't try to force-fit it into `<Integer, String>`.  It sounds like you need to refactor your other code.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Thanks, even I think so.. and considering to rewrite to accommodate this requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply need a *unique id* you might use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which (from the Javadoc) *defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the order in which keys were inserted into the map (insertion-order)*, if you were to then get the `keySet` you might construct an `ArrayList` and then use the index from that `List` as your *unique id*.

Answer (score 0):

Check out HashCodeBuilder in Apache Commons. It's about as close as you'll get - you just specify each element you want to the hash to take into consideration. What might make it work for you is that you can add anything, including constants you choose - so if you wanted to add the index of the map or anything you can think of to guarantee uniqueness, you can.

[Their documentation here has a pretty good example.](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang//apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/HashCodeBuilder.html)

It's just super flexible, so it should make this easier, at any rate!